# NetSuite saved search formula to multiply results of two other columns

Tags: oracle, formula, netsuite, saved-searches

I currently have a saved search that populates a list of items.
My current results are standard NetSuite fields which are "Name", "Description", "Type", "Average Cost" & "Available"

I am trying to add another column for a formula that multiplies the Average Cost by the Available to give me the Value of the Available SOH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your saved search results add a new field of type `formula(numeric)`. In the formula popup window use this formula:

```
NVL({averagecost}, 0) * NVL({quantityavailable}, 0)
```

This will multiply the average cost and quantity available together and give you the result. I put the NVL in there in case an item doesn't have an average cost or quantity available you won't get an error.